# How to make a vector like vec(x) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vector

I am trying to replicate this formula:

[image: formula]

I have gathered all variables in my workspace. However estimating `vec(Theta')` does not seem to work and so I am a little bit stuck.

```
Theta = A*B-C;
vTheta = vec(Theta');
```

`A`, `B` and `C` are defined. The problem is that MATLAB does not seem to know the function `vec` to do what I would like to do with `Theta` as in the formula.

[image: vec(Theta')]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you got that equation from, but `vec` is a function in R, maybe it's related to that? If you want to convert a matrix `Theta` into a vector, do

```
Theta(:)
```

Edit: If you need to transpose the matrix first, MATLAB might not let you do `Theta'(:)`. Instead do it in two steps:

```
tmp = Theta'; tmp(:)
```

Comment: This is the source code: 

http://read.pudn.com/downloads140/sourcecode/math/601411/GMM%20Libraries%20for%20Matlab/Utilities/kzspan.m__.htm

and this is the paper I got it from (p.29 pdf and p.173 paper)

http://apps.olin.wustl.edu/faculty/zhou/Span_KZ.pdf

Comment: Is that the MATLAB code that you're trying to run? Indeed it uses `vec`. I just now learned that Octave also defines a function `vec`. I had never seen this one before. Live and learn. In any case, the Octave `vec` does as I write in the answer.

Comment: I need to do exactly this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)

Comment: I know. This is what `Theta(:)` does to the matrix `Theta`. Try it out and see.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you have time for a last question? It is the 'last' error I found in the source code:

[junk,ST] = nwse(e,X,nlags);

It gives me an error that there are ''too many output arguments'', however it seems to work at the moment I delete ''junk'' and I make [ST] out of it. But because my script then runs fine, does it still give the results as it supposed to give?

I see this 'wrong' line 2 times in the code

[junk,ST] = nwse(e,X,nlags);

and 

[junk,S] = nwse(e,ones(T,1),nlags);

Comment: nwse is the name of the following function:

https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41275-newey-west-standard-errors?focused=3810088&tab=function&requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Comment: Maybe it's supposed to be [this function](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiErdfdgerXAhWKNd8KHUncBqE4ChAWCCowAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fr-forge.r-project.org%2Fscm%2Fviewvc.php%2F*checkout*%2Fpkg%2FPerformanceAnalytics%2Fsandbox%2FShubhankit%2FWeek6-7%2FCode%2FEquivalent%2520Matlab%2520Code%2Fnwse.m%3Frevision%3D2766%26root%3Dreturnanalytics%26pathrev%3D2766&usg=AOvVaw0ctEWAAZMeeFppUXDxcMM9)?

Comment: If the function has only one output argument, it's likely the one you need, but I can't be sure.

Comment: I am now going to take some rest. I will keep you updated  in about 10 hours.

Answer (score 0):

As written above the [Colon Operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) is the way vectorize defined variable.

Yet, sometime we want to vectorize a sub set of a variable.
Let's say we have a matrix - `mA` and we'd like to vectorize a sub section of it - `mA(2:3, 4:7)`.

One way is to define a new variable and vectorize it:

```
vA = mA(2:3, 4:7);
vA = vA(:);
```

Yet, what if we only wanted to use this inside another expression and only once?
Could we escape the need to generate explicit variable?

Well, unfortunately MATLAB doesn't have the [view()](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/devdocs/subarrays/) functionality like in [Julia](https://julialang.org/).
Yet if you want to avoid explicitly naming new variable (I'm not sure if MATLAB's JIT Engine can also void the memory allocation as Julia) you can do:

```
reshape(mA(2:3, 4:7), [], 1)
```

This will always yield a column vector.
You can also use:

```
reshape(mA(2:3, 4:7), 1, [])
```

To generate row vector.

For instance you can do:

```
reshape(mA(2:3, 4:7), 1, []) * reshape(mA(2:3, 4:7), [], 1, )
```

This will be the sum of squared values of those elements.